# How to upload a .csv file with multiple rows to Google Fusion Table from a Java application using new API?

Tags: google-fusion-tables

We have successfully connected to the fusion table through our java application but we have ran into issues with the rate upload limits when trying to upload each row individually. We then looked into dumping our SQL table into a .csv and uploading that but we cannot seem to find much documentation on this in the new API. We found the importRows API call but as mentioned the documentation is little to none. Has anyone successfully accomplished this or have any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, i can only give you pointers: in the PHP API client (version 0.6.0, which is the current one) the importRows method is not supported at all.
The reason is: this call is a little different from other RESTfull API calls. You are not POSTing any JSON objects in the body, instead it contains your CSV to upload. This approach just doesn't fit in the logic the API client is built around.

Chances are high that for the same reason the JAVA API client won't support it.

I was able to modify the API php code to support the import rows method and i shared it on [google-php-api issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/issues/detail?id=192#c7). Take a look, perhaps it gives you some clue on where to start.

Comment: Thanks for the response, worked great! I have successfully uploaded a .csv file with 40,000 rows.

Comment: As per v0.6.2 Google API client it's still not fixed. They have added importRows method but it is apparently impossible to use it (no way to provide request body data).

The only improvement I can suggest is that it's better to override __call in ServiceResource and private fields it depends on than to edit vendor source file. That, however, results in a lot of duplicated code :(